# ¿Cómo corregir los errores de conteo de palabras de un texto plano con PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Gracias a [Document Transformations](https://www.filestack.com/docs/api/processing/#document-transformations) de Filestack puedo obtener el contenido de archivos de Word (.DOC/.DOCX) en formato de texto plano (text/plain). Deseo contar el número de palabras (no números ni signos de puntuación) y mostrarlo en una página HTML. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<button type="button" id="load" class="btn btn-md btn-info">LOAD FILES</button>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
<script>

function numWordsR(urlk){ 
    $.post("result_filestack.php",{
        molk: urlk //urlk, ejemplo: https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/AXXXXAXeeeeW33A";
    }).done(function(resp){
        $("#result").html(resp);
    });
}
</script>
```

Y el archivo **result_filestack.php**:

```
$url = $_POST['molk'];
$content = file_get_contents($url); //obtengo el contenido del url en formato texto plano
$onlywords = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]\d]+/', '', $content); //sin números ni signos de puntuación

function get_num_of_words($string) {
  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));
  $words = explode(" ", $string);
  return count($words);
}

$numwords = get_num_of_words($onlywords);
echo "<b>TEXT:</b>: ".$onlywords."<br><br>Number of words: ".$numwords;
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, en este caso el resultado dice que el texto tiene 585 palabras, sin embargo si copio y pego este texto en MS Word me indica que tiene 612 palabras. Hago cambios en el código PHP para mapear el array del texto:

```
function get_text($string) {
  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));
  $words = explode(" ", $string);
  return $words;
}

$texto002 = get_text($onlywords);
echo print_r($texto002);
```

Estoy notando que existen errores en el conteo de palabras, en algunas partes están tomando dos o tres palabras como si fuese una sola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente pude corregirlo de la siguiente manera, utilizando la función `htmlentities()` ya que habían caracteres `&nbsp;`en el texto solo que no están visibles:

```
function get_num_of_words($string) {
  $string = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');
  $string = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $string);

  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));
  $words = explode(" ", $string);
  return count($words);
}
```